# How to use batch_insert in Code Igniter to insert an array into 1 column PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, bulkinsert

I have this function,

```
public function storeVals($vals)
{
    $vals = explode(",", $vals);

    foreach ($vals as $val)
    {
        $val = array('input'=>$val);

        $this->db->insert('input', $val);
    }
}
```

The function basically receives a string e.g: This,Is,An,Example

Then it turns the string into an array with "," as a delimiter.

Then it loops through the array and inserts the data into the DB.

Code Igniter, I think, already has the functionality to do this.

```
File: system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php

function _insert_batch($table, $keys, $values)
{
    return "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".implode(', ', $keys).") VALUES    ".implode(', ', $values);
}
```

Any ideas on how I can use insert_batch() instead of looping and inserting will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter, You can use `batch_insert` as:

```
public function storeVals($vals)
{
    $vals = explode(",", $vals);

    $yourArr = array();
    foreach ($vals as $val)
    {
        $yourArr[] = array('input'=>$val); // store values in array  
    }
    $this->db->insert('tableName', $yourArr);
}
```

**You can also follow the CI example:**

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'), ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

[Example Reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

[CI 3 User Guide (Batch Insert)](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert_batch#CI_DB_query_builder::insert_batch)